# how can i handle this error please in React native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

**i have this code

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator ,ScrollView,Text,Image} from 'react-native'
import { GetFilmDetailFromApi,GetImageFromApi } from '../API/tmdbApi'
import moment from 'moment'
import numeral from 'numeral'

class FilmDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      film: undefined,
      isLoading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    GetFilmDetailFromApi(this.props.navigation.state.params.idFilm).then(data => {
      this.setState({
        film: data,
        isLoading: false
      })
    })
  }

 



  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        {this._displayLoading()}
        {this._displayFilm()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}



export default FilmDetail
```

**but i got this error[image]**

** they told me that  this.props.navigation.state.paramas.idFilm is undefined
please someone can help me to find solution as soon as possible, the function GetFilmDetailFromApi is declared in another file here is here code**

```
const API_TOKEN = "aec60a6b4c98027dghfgjgjfdgjdf0a021";


// Récupération du détail d'un film
export function GetFilmDetailFromApi (id) {
  return fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id + '?api_key=' + API_TOKEN + '&language=fr')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
```

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for textual information

Answer (score 1):

i seen you this line code "import { GetFilmDetailFromApi,GetImageFromApi } from '../API/tmdbApi'", can you show this file code? "GetFilmDetailFromApi" is from this file.
maybe should check it.

Comment: i updated the question you can now see the function,but i dont think the probleme is from the function

Comment: oh. sorry. I didn't see the problem before. all right. you know  "this.props.navigation.state.params" from where? there is a problem with this parameter. you can try console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params) or console.log(this.props.navigation.state) or console.log(this.props.navigation)

Comment: Did the parameter value pass over when this navigation came over?

Comment: Follow @lllomh's advice. That's what you need to look at. You are being given a bad film id in the constructor's `props`. You need to find out why it's bad. The code you show here is probably not the problem. Look at the code that sets up the `props` object.

Answer (score 0):

i give you demo. hope can help you

Route: clear direction of jump:

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('Chat', { user: 'Lucy' })}
          title="Chat with Lucy"
        />
        
 const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
    Dsome:{screen:Dsome},
});
```

In the code, we have passed the user parameters to chat, so how can the chat page accept the parameters?

```
class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `Chat with ${navigation.state.params.user}`,
  });
  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat with {params.user}</Text>
      
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my writing demo. It's good